# RequireJS order plugin starts fetching in correct order but doesn't wait for the files to download?

Tags: jquery, download, requirejs

I'm trying to implement RequireJS in a project and i'm having some issues getting it to work correctly. If i've understood this correctly (and otherwise the plugin would be rather pointless), the order plugin downloads the scripts in the correct order, and waits for each model to download before executing the next one. Example:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min'
    }
});

require(['order!jquery', 'order!models/flyInModal'], function() {
    $('.fly-in-modal').flyInModal();
});
```

That should first download jquery from the path, and after jquery has loaded, continue to load flyInModal.js. Correct?

As of now, this is what's happening:

1. require.js loads
2. init-front.js loads
3. order.js loads
4. jquery *starts* loading
5. flyInModal.js loads
6. jquery finishes loading *after* flyInModal.js has loaded, causing errors because jQuery is missing

Screenshot of chrome dev tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A4fB.png

Have i misunderstood this, or is it working correctly now? I find order.js pretty pointless if it doesn't wait for the script to finish loading before continuing. Some scripts have a higher latency than others, that's just how it is.

Comment: Are you using RequireJS 2.x? If so the order plugin was deprecated in favour of using `shim` - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: Oh, i had missed that completely! I'll take a look at shim, thank you!

Comment: `shim` is indeed what i was looking for. If you go ahead and post it as an answer i'll accept that for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RequireJS 2.x `order` has been deprecated in favour of `shim` - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Details on why this was removed - https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-shim